# How to get path of image drag and dropped into PictureBox from flowlayoutpanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have simple app, I load through a button images into flowlayoutpanel as PictureBox forms. Then I need drag and drop these images in PictureBoxes.  Drag and drop works fine but I can't figure out how to get path of dropped image in PictureBox?

Here is part of my code:

```
private void SelectFilesButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeOpenFileDialog();
        DialogResult dr = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Read the files 
            foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames) 
            {
                soubory.AppendText(file+ System.Environment.NewLine);
                // Create a PictureBox.
                try
                {
                    PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
                    Image loadedImage = Image.FromFile(file);
                    pb.Height =100;
                    pb.Width = 100;
                    pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                    pb.Image = loadedImage;
                    pb.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(pb_MouseDown);
                    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pb);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Could not load the image - probably related to Windows file system permissions.
                    MessageBox.Show("Cannot display the image: " + file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('\\'))
                        + ". You may not have permission to read the file, or " +
                        "it may be corrupt.\n\nReported error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    void pb_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
    PictureBox img = sender as PictureBox;
    img.DoDragDrop(img.Image, DragDropEffects.Move);

    }
    void PictureBox1DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
    void PictureBox1DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        PictureBox1.Image = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);


    }
```

Comment: The picturebox is entirely unaware of the origin of the picture and so does not contain its original path.  One quick way would be to stuff it in the .Tag prop;  `pb.Tag = file;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Image.Tag` to pass information about path (because you are dragging `Image`):

```
void pb_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var img = (PictureBox)sender;
    img.Image.Tag = path; // this can be already set earlier or e.g. copied from pb.Tag (if pb.Tag is used to store path)
    img.DoDragDrop(img.Image, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

void PictureBox1DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox1.Image = (Image)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
    var path = PictureBox1.Image.Tag.ToString();
}
```

You can also define own data format to pass additional information. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17458188/1997232).

Comment: Thank you!  Using Tag is the best way how to deal with it.